# Nestjs mock Sequelize for unit-test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js, nestjs

I'm building a CRUD API using Nest.js and codding a unit-test for the service, but when I mock the Sequelize model, this is the code for the test:

```
import { getModelToken } from "@nestjs/sequelize";
import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing";

import { VacanciesService } from "../../vacancies.service";
import { DepartmentsServices } from "../../../departments/departments.service";
import { Departments } from "../../../departments/model/departments.model";
import { Vacancies } from "../../model/vacancies.model";

describe("Vacancies service", () => {
  let service: VacanciesService;

  const mockSequelizeDepartments = {
    findByPk: jest.fn(),
  };

  const mockSequelizeVacancies = {
    findAll: jest.fn(),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        VacanciesService,
        { provide: getModelToken(Vacancies), useValue: { mockSequelizeVacancies } },
        DepartmentsServices,
        { provide: getModelToken(Departments), useValue: { mockSequelizeDepartments } },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<VacanciesService>(VacanciesService);
  });

  it("should be defined", () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe("List vacancies", () => {
    it("should list all vacancies and return an empty array", async () => {
      const list = await service.list();

      expect(list).toHaveLength(0);
      expect(mockSequelizeVacancies.findAll).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

But when i run the test, it show the following error:

```
TypeError: this.vacanciesModel.findAll is not a function

      57 |
      58 |   async list() {
    > 59 |     const list = await this.vacanciesModel.findAll();
         |                                            ^
      60 |
      61 |     if (!list) throw new NotFoundException("Nenhuma vaga encontrada");
      62 |
```

I've already tried to change the findAll to "findAll() { "Do something" }" or "findAll: () => { "Do something" }" and stilll the same error.

How can i fix this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `useValue` from `useValue: { mockSequelizeVacancies }` to be `useValue: mockSequelizeVacancies`.

The first, you're making an object with the key `mockSequelizeVacancies` and value `{ findAll: jest.fn() }`, the second you're just injecting the object `{ findAll: jest() }`